# What are contradications or threats of running own application from C:\Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012

My colleagues are testing our new system (.Net 4) app and running it directly from C:\Windows.

App is executed in each user session within user context (so, with lower rights really).

I've noticed that there is a serious problem with this app. I can't read full filename path of app (from another application) by retrieving it using process class (MainModule.FileName) - Access Denied, nor by using WMI query - here I get empty string. UAC is turned off.

Both methods work fine in developing environment (different paths). Is there any way I can adjust security settings, or I just should give up and change the path to something more neutral?

Comment: Since you _know_ you're not supposed to do that, and you _know_ that programs should be in one of the "Program Files" folders, _why_ would you want to do this?

Comment: Exactly. Or consider the opposite question: "What are the indications or benefits of running own application from `C:\Windows`?" You've already identified some problems. So if you cannot come up with any significant benefits, then why not make your life easier and do it the usual way.

Comment: Because it wasn't my call (but my supervisors), and now i'd like to just have some arguments to convince them it's really a bad idea. My question is simple, i might be a bit rude now (sorry), but i asked a technical question, not a philosophical one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just give up and change the path to "something more neutral". I.e. a proper installation directory in the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` directory (as appropriate).

Also, it is not clear from your question *why* you want to retrieve the full file path of the process, but it's likely you're going about that wrong as well. There's really no reason that a program should be forced to run from any specific directory, so if you have a system that is somehow relying on a check of the full file path of the process's executable, that system is probably flawed and should be using some other mechanism for the purpose (e.g. using shared memory, a named pipe, a named mutex, or other similar inter-process communications mechanism).

Comment: There is a reason, we have another app which is watching some (different) processes ran in memory and executes them in case they fail, regardless of their origin launch path (it's reading execution path from processes). So, it can be changed, but it won't work universally. Though i'd like to know something more about behaviour of apps launched from C:\Windows, i'am selecting you answer as accepted. Thanks.